# Insert the result of an insert into another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

With PostgreSQL, given the following tables :

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE event_details (
  uuid UUID NOT NULL,
  signal_strength SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  event_id INTEGER REFERENCES events (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_id)
);
```

To insert an event, I must insert the event details first, then insert the "generic" event after, linking with the event details. I have built this query to do this :

```
INSERT INTO event_details VALUES ('B9056867-459D-4F0B-8627-7456C880F54B', 50, (INSERT INTO events VALUES (DEFAULT, '2014-03-21 15:37:44.683081-04') RETURNING id));
```

But I get this error : ***ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"***

So I can't insert a value with an `INSERT INTO` like I would do with a `SELECT`. How can I forward the newly created row id into the foreign key column of event_details?

There may be a lot of these queries when the system will be running, so I would like to avoid retrieving the id back in my code (in NodeJS) and then do the second `INSERT` in a separate statement.

Thanks!

PS : I simplified the SQL of the tables, but I have some good reasons to separate event_details with events (there are many event types with different details).

**[edit]**

The right way to do it, in this situation, is :

`WITH new_event AS (INSERT INTO events VALUES (DEFAULT, '2014-03-21 15:37:44.683081-04') RETURNING id) INSERT INTO event_details VALUES ('B9056867-459D-4F0B-8627-7456C880F54B', 50, (SELECT id FROM new_event LIMIT 1));`

Thanks to Jaffar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22569636/1287598) for this solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL has such an extended interpretation of the VALUES clause that it may be used as a subquery by itself.

So you may express your query in this form:

```
WITH new_invoice AS (
    INSERT INTO ...
    RETURNING id
),
v(a,b,c,d) AS (values
  ($27,$28,$29,$30),
  ($31,$32,$33,$34),
  ...
)
INSERT INTO invoiceItems (invoice_id, name, qty, price, description)
 SELECT new_invoice.id, a,b,c,d FROM v, new_invoice;
```

That assumes you want to insert the cartesian product of new_invoice and the values, which mostly makes sense if new_invoice is actually a single-row value.

Comment: It worked like a charm with the `WITH ... AS ...` solution. Thanks! My query now looks like : `WITH new_event AS (INSERT INTO events VALUES (DEFAULT, '2014-03-21 15:37:44.683081-04') RETURNING id) INSERT INTO event_details VALUES ('B9056867-459D-4F0B-8627-7456C880F54B', 50, (SELECT id FROM new_event LIMIT 1));`

Answer (score 0):

You must separate the queries since an insert-subquery is not a valid value expression:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-expressions.html

Or you can make a stored procedure. That reduces the overhead.

Comment: you shouldn't link (or use) the manual of a totally outdated version. Check out Jaffar's answer, this is indeed possible in current Postgres versions.

Comment: Well sorry, it has not change thought. I've updated the link and an insert is still not allowed to use as an expression value.

Comment: Did you see Jaffar's answer?